# cant import distribution_identity.cer to keychain access

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, keychain

im getting this same problem over and over again. im developing an app for the iphone and already imported my developer.cer to keychain access and it showed up in keychain acess in one of my keys. but later i make a distribuation provisioning profile and import it to xcode. it Has an error(see pic for details).
so i go to the apple provisioning portal and find my distribution certificate. i download it and go to keychain access and click File>Import Items...
I click on my distribution_identity.cer From my downloads folder and nothing happens. no error no nothing. but when i look into the "certificates" tab i see my distribution certificate. but its not in a key like the other. Please Help!!!!
[Error in xCODE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoRnK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, and I got round it by revoking the Distribution Certificate and generating a new one. The instructions on how to do so are available when you click the button to generate a new one.

Obviously the downside to this is that if you have any Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles, they will stop working and you will need to renew them and download them again.

Hope this works for you like it did for me!